# Kivy manages multiple pages and widgets

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Goodmorning everyone. I have a problem with the management of widgets within the application that I am developing with kivy. If I use only one page (window) everything works fine. If I add a page as you can see from the code I get errors of this type. I can't solve them, can you give me a hand?

```
self.root.ids["mdlabel"].text = "Hello"
 KeyError: 'mdlabel'
```

The code I used is the following:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV="""

ScreenManager:
    MainWindow:
        name: "screen1"
    SecondWindow:
        name: "screen2"
    
<MainWindow>:
    id: screen1
    RelativeLayout:
        
    MDTextField:
        id: mdtext
        hint_text: "No helper text"
        pos: (120,120)
        
    MDLabel:
        id: mdlabel
        text: "No helper text"
        pos: (0,120)
                    
    MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
        id: mdbu
        text: "Invia"
        on_press: app.fun()
        pos: (0, 10)
            
    MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
        id: mdbu_cambia1
        text: "Order"
        on_press: app.root.current = "screen2"
        pos: (250, 10)      
        
<SecondWindow>:
    id: screen2
    RelativeLayout:
    MDTextField:
        id: testo_2
        hint_text: "Testo2"
        pos: (10,150)
    
    MDRectangleFlatIconButton:
        id: mdbu_cambia
        text: "Back"
        on_press: app.root.current = "screen1"
        pos: (250, 10)   

"""

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.title = "Ciao Mondo"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def fun(self):
        self.root.ids["mdlabel"].text = "Hello"


MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `id` (`mdlabel`) that you are trying to access is defined in the `MainWindow` rule, but you are trying to access it as though it were defined in the app root. The app root is the `ScreenManager`.

You can fix it by either:

1. Move the `fun()` method into the `MainWindow` and change the button `on_press:` to `on_press: root.fun()`
2. Or change the `fun()` method to access the `MainWindow` `Screen` as `self.root.get_screen("screen1").ids["mdlabel"].text = "Hello"`